# error while installing anaconda: chosen path already exists

Tags: anaconda

while installing anaconda using graphic installer on macOS, i'm getting an error after the destination select step saying the chosen path already exists even though i've never installed anaconda before. After trying again and changing the destination location also, there is an error saying there's space in the path. please help me out, I'm not able to install anaconda on my laptop.

i want to install anaconda and i used the graphic installer[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyut1.png)